# Android/C# Socket - Decode/Enconde String64 Error after 1 frame (Almost Complete)

Tags: c#, android, sockets, bitmap

I created a C# server that sends an Bitmap through a socket to android client. That Bitmap is constantly updating because it's a video feed.

Server C#

```
  private void send_data()
    {
                    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();                
                    byte[] sendBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(master.picturebox_master.Image, typeof(byte[]));



                    string_master_frame = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sendBytes);
                    string_master_frame = Convert.ToBase64String(sendBytes);

                    data = string_master_frame + "\n";


                    tcpServer1.Send(data);
    }
```

Client Android

```
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            Scanner r = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while(true) {

                valores[26] = r.nextLine();

                publishProgress(valores[26]);
            }

    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(values[26],Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Bitmap master_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString,0,decodedString.length);
    master_frame.setImageBitmap(master_bitmap);

}
```

The first frame is sent and the Android client displays it correctly. But when the next frame comes, the Android Client Crashes.

Error:

> Process: com.example.tiago.java_android, PID: 826
>                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
>                                                                                   at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
>                                                                                   at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
>                                                                                   at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
>                                                                                   at com.example.tiago.java_android.Cliente.onProgressUpdate(Cliente.java:228)
>                                                                                   at com.example.tiago.java_android.Cliente.onProgressUpdate(Cliente.java:28)
>                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:656)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)

I though the valores[26] data was being corrupted but it's not. I get the data correctly.

I used http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter to check if I get the data correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: `The first frame is sent and the Android client displays it correctly. But when the next frame comes, the Android Client Crashes.`. Well why did not you tell that before? And how is it possible that you post now under a different name? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040070/android-receving-an-image-over-the-socket-from-c-sharp-server-almost-complete?noredirect=1#comment65431064_39040070 You have two accounts?

Comment: if you catch the `IllegalArgumentException` then your app will not crash.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError`. What are you asking? The device has not enough memory to make a Bitmap out of it.

Comment: I will remove my edit. Because That's not the problem. The problem is the first error.

Comment: ` String[] safe = values[26].split("=");` Why? Does not make any sense. Now that you tried all kind of decoding in Android its time you try a different encoding in C#.

Comment: I know sorry. I dont have that code anymore.

Comment: Please leave the out of memory error.

Comment: I just cant understand why I get the right string the first time and then it gives me that error.

Comment: Which error? IllegalArgument or out of memory?

Comment: `I get the data correctly.`. How did you check?

Comment: What is the resolution of your bitmap in pixels?